# Getting difference in number of days between two Calendar input by user

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a form to find out how many days a person has been staying at a certain place. So for example a person were to input Start Date: 22/02/2021 and End Date: 18/05/2021, the page have to display "86" as the difference.

So far, this is what I have :

```js
function calculateDate() {
  var startDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
  var endDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
  var Difference_In_Time = endDate.value() - startDate.value();
  var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  document.getElementById("taxResidencyCalculator").innerHTML = Difference_In_Days;
}
```

```html
<h2>Tax Residency Calculator</h2>

<p>To calculate the difference between two dates user choose from Start Date and End Date</p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="startDate">Start Date:</label>
  <input type="date" id="startDate" name="startDate" required><br><br>
  <label for="endDate">End Date:</label>
  <input type="date" id="endDate" name="endDate" required><br><br>
  <button onclick="calculateDate()">Calculate</button>


  <p id="taxResidencyCalculator"></p>

</form>
```

Currently my codes that I have attached is not working. At best, I am only able to get the date out of one calendar or Get a default date that has been given a value in the codes instead of getting it from user. Need your good help how can I get the difference between two dates input by user.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for. A great library I'd recommend for dealing with dates: https://date-fns.org/

Comment: Your snippet doesn't seem to be working for some reason, it flashes a console error.

Comment: @thursday_dan because there's no `value()` function for a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `Date` Object from the user inputted date, and use `getTime()` method, to get the time in milliseconds. Then you can subtract them, and convert it into days.

```js
function calculateDate() {
  var startDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
  var endDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
  var Difference_In_Time = new Date(endDate).getTime() - new Date(startDate).getTime();
  var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  document.getElementById("taxResidencyCalculator").innerHTML = Difference_In_Days;
}
```

```html
<h2>Tax Residency Calculator</h2>

<p>To calculate the difference between two dates user choose from Start Date and End Date</p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="startDate">Start Date:</label>
  <input type="date" id="startDate" name="startDate" required><br><br>
  <label for="endDate">End Date:</label>
  <input type="date" id="endDate" name="endDate" required><br><br>


  <p id="taxResidencyCalculator"></p>

</form>

<button onclick="calculateDate()">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this if it's working for you.

```js
function calculateDate() {
  var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("startDate").value);
  var endDate = new Date(document.getElementById("endDate").value);
  var Difference_In_Time = Math.abs(endDate - startDate);
  var Difference_In_Days = Math.ceil(Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 

  document.getElementById("taxResidencyCalculator").innerHTML = Difference_In_Days;
}
```

```html
<h2>Tax Residency Calculator</h2>

<p>To calculate the difference between two dates user choose from Start Date and End Date</p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="startDate">Start Date:</label>
  <input type="date" id="startDate" name="startDate" required><br><br>
  <label for="endDate">End Date:</label>
  <input type="date" id="endDate" name="endDate" required><br><br>
  <button onclick="calculateDate()">Calculate</button>


  <p id="taxResidencyCalculator"></p>

</form>
```